# Sublime Latexing and Knitr on .RNW files : Send lines to R console for evaluation

Tags: r, knitr, sublime-text

I am using Sublime Text 3 and the Latexing package to apply Knitr to compile .Rnw files that contain both Latex and R code.  Overall, it works well in that I can compile the .Rnw files into PDFs nicely.  But, I am not able to get an important piece of functionality to work as compared to what I have in .R files.

Specifically, I am not able to send small pieces of code to R without compiling whole .Rnw file.  I can compile the entire .Rnw file just fine, and that will of course evaluate all of the code chunks that I have knit into the document and create the PDF.  I would like to be able to send small pieces of code to be evaluated in the R console without needing to compile the entire .Rnw file.  (This is essentially what you can do in R Studio, and is useful for figuring out whether the code that I am including in the .Rnw file does what I want it to do without needing to compile the entire .Rnw file each time or without needing to copy/paste it into some other running R console).  When I am just editing a .R document, I can do this via Command + Enter (using the Enhanced R package for Sublime) but this also doesn't work when editing a .Rnw document.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to send it via REPL to the R console right within Sublime.

Are there ways to accomplish this in Sublime that I don't know about, or are they just features that have yet to be developed?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935129/unable-to-send-r-code-from-a-knitr-document-to-sublimerepl/26357267#26357267), and I managed to fix it following [this](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/165#issuecomment-57658359) recommendation at least for latextools, it may be the same for latexing.
`/R/Main.sublime-menu` file has to be edited:

(which in Ubuntu is in:
`~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/R/Main.sublime-menu`)

and the additional scope has to be modified in this way:

```
 "additional_scopes": ["tex.latex.knitr.ing"]
```

Comment: Hallelujah, it works!  Thanks!  It was that extra ".ing" that the file needed.  Why it would need it, I have no idea, but it works.  I'm on OS, and the path to the file for me was:  /Users/User_Name/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/R/Main.sublime-menu

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed a functionality that the LaTeXing package offers, thanks to @RandyLai's Sublime Text package [Enhanced-R](https://github.com/randy3k/Enhanced-R) (or its refactoring [R-Box](https://github.com/randy3k/R-Box)) as per [this bit](http://docs.latexing.com/stable/tutorials/knitr-with-latexing.html) of LaTeXing's documentation. The default key binding, which works for me, is `command`/`ctrl` + `b`, depending on whether you have an Apple keyboard or not.

I assume you have the requisite ST packages installed: LaTeXing, Enhanced-R/R-Box, [SublimeKnitr](https://github.com/andrewheiss/SublimeKnitr) (called "knitr" in Package Control). A few reasons why it may not work for you:

- when you are writing your .Rnw, perhaps you aren't using the "LaTeXing (Knitr)" syntax
- perhaps you, like me, don't use the standard Sweave syntax, i.e., delimiting R code with `<<>>=` and `@`, for your code chunks